# UIImage resizes unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uipangesturerecognizer

I have View Controller inside the View Controller I have placed a UIImageView I am trying to draw on the image present in the UIImageView in this manner.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [self.drawImageView setImage:editableImage];
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(drawingViewDidPan:)];
 panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
 self.drawImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 [self.drawImageView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
}
```

Where drawImageView is my UIImageView and editableImage is the UIImage I am trying to draw on.

I am implementing the drawing part as follows

```
- (void)drawingViewDidPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
  CGPoint currentDraggingPosition = [sender locationInView:drawImageView];

  if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
     prevDraggingPosition = currentDraggingPosition;
  }

  if(sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
      [self drawLine:prevDraggingPosition to:currentDraggingPosition];
  }
  prevDraggingPosition = currentDraggingPosition;
}

-(void)drawLine:(CGPoint)from to:(CGPoint)to
{
  CGSize size = drawImageView.frame.size;
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  [drawImageView.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

  CGFloat strokeWidth = 5.0;
  UIColor *strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];

  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, strokeWidth);
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor.CGColor);
  CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);


  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, from.x, from.y);
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, to.x, to.y);
  CGContextStrokePath(context);

  drawImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

The problem is as soon as I place my finger to draw the UIImage resizes and becomes small rest all works good

How can I solve this ?

My editableImage is coming from another viewcontroller which has a button called draw

```
-(IBAction)drawOnOmage:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue1" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  ThirdViewController *destinationController = (ThirdViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
  destinationController->editableImage = self.editImage.image;
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and show us where does `editableImage` come from!

Comment: I just did but the image that comes is all good once i touch the image it gets resize

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code to a new project and it seems to work for me. The only thing I notice is that you are not using a `@property` declaration for `prevDraggingPosition` - maybe this is the problem? Can you show us how you declare `prevDraggingPosition`?

Have a look at my example (that works for me, I only added `self.`):

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *drawImageView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint prevDraggingPosition;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(drawingViewDidPan:)];
    panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    self.drawImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.drawImageView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

}

- (void)drawingViewDidPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    CGPoint currentDraggingPosition = [sender locationInView:self.drawImageView];

    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        self.prevDraggingPosition = currentDraggingPosition;
    }

    if(sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        [self drawLine:self.prevDraggingPosition to:currentDraggingPosition];
    }
    self.prevDraggingPosition = currentDraggingPosition;
}

-(void)drawLine:(CGPoint)from to:(CGPoint)to
{
    CGSize size = self.drawImageView.frame.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [self.drawImageView.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    CGFloat strokeWidth = 5.0;
    UIColor *strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, strokeWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);


    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, from.x, from.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, to.x, to.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    self.drawImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

@end
```

Comment: I added prevDraggingPosition as a public variable in my interface file.

Comment: If you make it a `@property` as I show you in my example above, it does not work?

Comment: Edit your question and add how you declare `prevDraggingPosition` and `drawImageView`

Comment: The image in my case is coming from another view controller will that cause a problem